# Как правильно записать Е2 — Е4? Как есть?

Tags: пунктуация

Это просто подпись под фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Е2 — Е4**

---

Отбивается ли тире?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте новые метки узкой направленности!

Comment: Но шахматная запись - это тоже русский язык! Сколько в спецлитературе опубликовано шахматных партий! Я сама делала корректуру их, и ошибок в оформлении проходить не должно! Верните, пожалуйста, мою метку.

Comment: Если эта метка действительно окажется нужной и на сайте появится добрая сотня вопросов о традиции записи шахматных ходов, я обязательно верну ее. На данный момент она лишь может пополнить список меток-призраков.

Comment: будьте добры, прочитайте статью о метках в справочном центре :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ход пешки записывается без указания фигуры, т.е. только полями: е2—е4. Ход остальных фигур обозначается по схеме Кр а5—b6. Сокращённая запись ходов может не содержать тире: Сc4 Кc6.

Comment: А если это **е2—е4** единственно и составляет подпись под снимком, неужели буквы, особенно первая, строчные?

Comment: Почему же нет? Это специфическая форма сродни записи формул, уравнений, где первый и прочие члены пишутся со строчной или так, как принято.

Answer (score 0):

Тире (иногда встречается и дефис) без пропусков:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F